# Symmetrized Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, trace

Let $A$ be an operator on $H^{n} = H \otimes H \otimes ... \otimes H$ and $W$ be a statistical operator on $H^{n}$. A text books says, if $A$ is symmetric, thenfor any $W$

$Tr(AW) = Tr(AW_{sym})$

and if $W$ is symmetric, then for any$A$,

$Tr(AW)=Tr(A_{sym}W)$.

What is this function $Tr()$? When what does the above exactly signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is the trace of the operator $A$.  It is defined to be

$$\operatorname{Tr}(A) = \sum_n \langle e_n, Ae_n\rangle$$

where $\{e_n\}$ is any basis of the relevant Hilbert space.  In this case,

$$Tr(AW)=\sum_n\langle e_n, AWe_n\big)\rangle$$
However, since $W\phi=\sum_n e_n \langle e_n,W\phi\rangle$ (the resolution of the identity), it follows that

$$\operatorname{Tr}(AW)=\sum_n\langle e_n, A\sum_m e_m \langle e_m,W e_n\rangle \rangle$$
$$= \sum_n\sum_m\langle e_n,Ae_m\rangle\langle e_m,We_n\rangle \equiv \sum_n\sum_m A_{nm} W_{mn}$$

That is, it is the sum of the diagonal entries of the matrix product of $A$ with $W$.  Framed in this way, the result is straightforward.  If $A$ is symmetric, then $A_{nm}=A_{mn}$. If $W$ is antisymmetric, then $W_{nm}=-W_{mn}$.  Then we would have that

$$\sum_{n,m}A_{nm}W_{mn}=-\sum_{n,m}A_{mn}W_{nm} \implies \sum_{n,m}A_{nm}W_{mn}=0$$

Since any operator can be written as the sum of a symmetric part and an antisymmetric part, this is just the statement that when calculating the trace of a product of two operators, if one of them is symmetric, we need only consider the symmetric part of the other.